# nginx rewrite specific folder to php and arg

Tags: nginx

Am trying to redirect
domain.tld/blog/read.php?article=first-article to domain.tld/blog/first-article

What I tried and didn't work resulting in redirect to domain.tld/first-article

```
location "^blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```

```
location /blog {
 rewrite ^/blog/?$ /blog/read.php?article=? last;
 rewrite ^/blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /blog/read.php?article=$1? last;
}
```

```
location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```

Thinking the issue comes from my other parts in the config and mainly second location from below

```
server {
...
...
location ~ "^/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /device.php?name=$1;
}

location ~ "^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /device.php?name=$1&crversion=$2;
}
...
```

Any pointers would help a lot
Cheers

Comment: I miss here what is the business related question in here. moreover, I miss a error and question in general as also what the Logs says...? ;)

Comment: @djdomi Am trying to redirect domain.tld/blog/read.php?article=first-article to domain.tld/blog/first-article

    There isn't a specific error, since nginx says all find in config, yet I get wrong redirect on site

Comment: managed to fix it  problem was that I was putting it last in the config and configuration is checked top bottom with first match being chosen

Comment: please add the last comment as an answer with a full description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fast answer is actually the fact that my config was fine first time, yet nginx config is read top bottom with first match being the one that is used.
So in the end the "fix" was adding the blog part upper in the site config

```
location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```